# Evaluating a postfix string expression using stacks in Java

Tags: java, stack, expression

I'm currently trying to implement an evaluate method for a calculator program in Java.

```
public double evaluate() {
StringStack stack = new StringStack();
double result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < postfixTokens.size(); i++) {
    if (!isOperator(postfixTokens.get(i))) {
        stack.push(postfixTokens.get(i));   //pushes operands to the stack
    }else if (isOperator(postfixTokens.get(i))) {   
        double op1 = Double.parseDouble(stack.pop());   //pops two operands to perform an operation
        double op2 = Double.parseDouble(stack.pop());
        switch(postfixTokens.get(i)) {
            case "+": result = op1 + op2; break;
            case "-": result = op2 - op1; break;
            case "/": result = op2 / op1; break;
            case "*": result = op1 * op2; break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

An error occurs saying the stack is empty whenever I try to evaluate an expression with more than one operator such as 5+5+5.  Expressions with only one operator such as 5+5 work fine though. Where am I going wrong in my code?

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that you need to push `result` into the `stack` again

Comment: The stack is a String stack.  Should I convert from a double back to a string again?

Comment: Actually, why do you use a `String` stack? Why not use `Double` stack instead?

Comment: It's required for the assignment to use a String stack

Comment: I see, well, then you have no other choice than to convert the Double back to String.

Answer (score 0):

> An error occurs saying the stack is empty whenever I try to evaluate an expression with more than one operator such as 5+5+5.

It occurs whenever you try to evaluate an expression that isn't legal postfix.

> Expressions with only one operator such as 5+5 work fine though.

No they don't. The code you posted gives an `EmptyStackException` for 5+5.

> Where am I going wrong in my code?

You are't going 'wrong in your code'. You're going wrong in your test data. 5+5+5 is not a postfix expression. It is an infix expression. The correct postfix for that is 555++.

5+5 is not a postfix expression either.

However you do have a bug. You need to push the result of each operator, and return the conversion of `stack.pop()` to a double. And you don't need to check `isOperator()` in the `else` block of `!isOperator()`.